# Why does this simple Powershell script not exit when needed?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a simple Powershell script derived [from here](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created) which is supposed to exit when a certain condition becomes true (file deleted, modified, etc.)

The script:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder\"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$continue = $true

$action = { 
            Write-Host "Action..."
            $anexe = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\aprogram.exe"
            $params = "-d filename"
            Start $anexe $params
            $continue = $false
          }    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($continue) {sleep 1}
```

As you can see, the script is supposed to exit when condition is met (an "action" is taken) since value of continue changes to `false` and the loop should then end and the script should exit. However, it keeps going. The loop is endless even when the condition is met.

I have also tried to use `exit` [to exit out of the powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022326/terminating-a-script-in-powershell). Does not work either. I tried removing the `sleep 1`, however, then it ends up killing my cpu because of the infinite loop without any time gap.

How can I fix it to exit when the file change condition is met?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell and System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795933/powershell-and-system-io-filesystemwatcher)

Comment: @Theo: The linked post is related, but not a duplicate, because _this_ issue is about using a variable inside the event handler to communicate information to the main script..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$action` event-handler script block doesn't run in the same scope as your script<sup>[1]</sup>, so your script never sees the `$continue` variable you set inside the script block.

As a workaround, you can:

- initialize a *global* variable named `$continue` in your script: `$global:continue = $true`
- then set that variable in your event-handler script block: `$global:continue = $false`
- and check that global variable's value in your script's loop: `while ($global:continue) {sleep 1}`
- be sure to remove your global variable before exiting the script, as it would otherwise linger in the session: `Remove-Variable -Scope Global count`.

  - Also, generally, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) soundly advises, be sure to properly dispose of the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` instance once you're done watching: `$watcher.Dispose()`.

---

<sup>[1] It runs in the same session, but inside a [dynamic module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module).</sup>